# 5V Tolerant Way To Generate Rising Edge Signal on USB Connection

Tags: usb, circuit-design, interrupts, best-practice

I have a microcontroller device that can be awakened from deep sleep mode when it detects a rising edge signal on a wakeup pin. The wakeup pin is 5V tolerant and I'd like a connection to a USB port to generate the rising edge signal. Originally I was just going to have the Vusb generate that rising edge on connection along with a pull down resistor but somebody pointed out that Vusb can be very noisy and have large transients especially on attach. The following image shows my USB input circuitry as currently designed.

[image: USB Power Input]

I've had some people tell me that a pulldown (10k) paired with a small (0.1uF) cap on the wakeup pin using Vusb directly will do the trick but another person recommended a buffer IC like a non-inverter buffer with schmitt trigger.

Are they both right or is one clearly a better option than the other? Is there another generally accepted approach that would be better for generating the rising edge when USB power is connected?

Comment: Try the basic pulldown, plus a safety resistor between the pulled-down Vbus and the wakeup pin.  (in case a software bug makes it an output, or a large transient activates the ESD diodes, or whatever)  You might get multiple triggers, but is that a problem?  Do you naturally react to the first edge and ignore the rest anyway?  If you do repeat a triggered action, is it actually a problem?  There might be a case for better filtering, but I'm not seeing it here.

Comment: If the goal is to wake a uP up on USB attach, why would you worry about any transients? Also the VBUS can't be too "noisy", maximum +-0.5V. A pull-down resistor is a must however, and a 1:1.5 divider is even better.

Comment: @AaronD Great point. The pin only responds to the initial rising edge and is not affected by any subsequent triggers.

Comment: @AliChen I guess the concern on transients is that the VBUS line from a computer or laptop or even a charging brick could experience a large voltage spike during the connection process. I don't know if that's really something of concern or not.

Comment: Which connection process? If it is a connection to the device under question, then there will be some contact bouncing for sure, but the wake-up process should be designed to tolerate this. I am not sure however about what is your use model at all.

Comment: @AliChen Yes, I meant during the physical connection of the cable. If the voltage spikes during that moment how much of a concern is it given your suggested approach in the answer?

Comment: @K-Sid It won't spike then, just bounce.  But I guess it's possible to have an inductive kick.  For example, a lot of hosts don't enforce the current spec at all, so you can simply (ab)use them as generic 5V power supplies.  Unplug a big load from a long extension, and everything else on that extension gets a spike.  That should never happen per the USB spec, but you know users...

Comment: @AaronD so you'd agree that Ali's suggested answer is sufficient given nothing else crazy on the port/hub my device plugs into?

Comment: @K-Did Yep, that's fine.  The cap will slow it down by a handful of milliseconds, but you probably won't notice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a uP pin is "5V tolerant", it doesn't mean that you need to push the input pad to its maximim. A standard level (I assume it is a 3.3V uP) would be just fine to wake the uP up. Here is the standard circuit to handle VBUS connect event:

[image]

Anything "better" like a buffer or else will be an overkill.